# set form fields when buttons are pressed

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I have an html page saved with a PHP extension.  It contains an input form with two fields home_page_text and aff_page_text. It also contains two buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
 <body bgcolor="#EEE8AA">
  <form name="Form1" id="Form1" action="post_message.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="400" 
  name="home_page_text" id="home_page_text"
  value="" style="background-color:#EFD381" />

  <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="400" 
  name="aff_page_text" id="aff_page_text"
  value="" style="background-color:#EFD381" />

  <input class="stand_alone_button_left_12em" type="button" value="Default The Message" 
  name="default_home" 
  onclick="return OnButton1();" />

  <input class="stand_alone_button_left_12em" type="button" value="Default The Message" 
  name="default_aff" 
  onclick="return OnButton2();" />
```

I'd like to have each of the two fields set with a different default value whenever a corresponding button is pressed.

So if I pressed button **default_home** I'd like the field **home_page_text** set to "This is the HOME PAGE default value". Correspondingly, if I pressed button **default_aff** I'd like the field **aff_page_text** set to "This is the AFF PAGE default value".

The values should be default only. The user could accept the text as is, or edit the default text.  When a third button (type = submit) is pressed, the page would be submitted causing the Post to call a page like "post_message.php".

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the jQuery library installed for this project? It's much easier to accomplish with jQuery, otherwise you'll have to use plain JavaScript.

Pretty much, when the **default_home** button is pressed, jQuery will set the home_page_text to whatever you'd like, and the same thing if the other button is pressed.

Otherwise, you can accomplish this with Ajax, or even PHP.  With PHP, it would require a whole page refresh whenever a different button is pressed.

Let me know how you want to solve this: PHP, jQuery, or Ajax (jQuery is the most efficient)

Comment: I've used jquery.cycle.all.js in the past.  I called it this way:  <!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I just checked HostGator (my hosting server) and realize that they support jquery.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved even with plain javascript as well. If default_home button is pressed, in OnButton1() method you can able to modify the value of the input as below,

```
document.getElementById("home_page_textotc").value = "This is the HOME PAGE default value";
```

In the same way, In OnButton2() method,

```
document.getElementById("aff_page_textThis is the AFF PAGE default value").value = "This is the HOME PAGE default value";
```